# Angular 2:How to display html based on duration between times

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

code component.ts

```
  getduration(Calmodel) {
        console.log(Calmodel.DateFrom);
        this.DateFrom = new Date(Calmodel.DateFrom);
        this.DateTo = new Date(Calmodel.DateTo);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(this.DateTo.getTime() - this.DateFrom.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        // alert(diffDays);
        console.log(diffDays);
    }
```

From this above code i am getting duration between times in diffDays,
Now how should i display different html based on duration, example if it is 1hour duration then should display green color html and if it is 2 hour duration should dispaly in some other color,

please help me,i am newer to angular 2.
Thank you

Comment: So you want dynamic styles? Check out this guide: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/

Comment: @ Pramod Ramadand: My answer is correct or not?

Comment: You can define CSS classes then apply with condition with `[class]="{"cls1": condition1, "cls2": condition2}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also start this timer is your required date/time.

Please read more details: [Rxjs Timer](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md)

I have also mention demo example:

**Your Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
    <div *ngIf="isShow"> Show Html 1</div>
    <div *ngIf="!isShow"> Show Html 2</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private timer;
  private isShow:boolean=false;
  ngOnInit() {

    // First argument is how to start timer AND second is what time interval
    this.timer = Observable.timer(5000,5000); // I have set time duration is 5 second. set your time duration.
    this.timer.subscribe(t => this.displayThis(t));
  }

  displayThis(t){
    console.log(t);
    if(this.isShow){
      this.isShow = false;
    }else{
      this.isShow = true;
    }
  }
}
```